# higher order function filter method of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a generateBtn method here, and I also used Auth as HOC

```
@Auth
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    generateBtn(){ return <button>Submit</button> }
    render(){
       return(<div>hello world {this.generateBtn()}</div>)
    }
}
```

In my Auth I have this

```
export default function Auth(WrappedComponent) {
        return class WithAuth extends Component {

          render() {
             // how to filter generateBtn method?
             return <WrappedComponent />
          }
        }
    }
```

But how to filter out generateBtn method?

Comment: What do you mean "filter out" generateBtn method?

Comment: @EmadEmami do not render that function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you can check for a custom prop in the wrapped component:

```
@Auth
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  generateBtn(){
    return <button>Submit</button>
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        hello world { this.props.hasAuth && this.generateBtn() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And pass that prop according to logic from the **HOC**:

```
export default function Auth(WrappedComponent) {
  return class WithAuth extends Component {

    render() {
      // You'll have some way of knowing if authentication was
      // correct here, let's hardcode `false` for now
      const authenticated = false

      return <WrappedComponent hasAuth={ authenticated } />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if I have 1000 MyComponent, I have to do the logic in 1000 MyComponent? I want to pass a method name from @auth, the do the hiding/filtering logic in HOC, isn't that easier?

Comment: You can pass anything you want of course. But what would be different with this version? You have to add a bit of logic to the 1000 components some way or another..

Comment: If I do the hiding logic within the hoc, then I can simply add @auth in my 1000 components, need not to do the hiding logic within the 1000 components.

Comment: So you want to alter the behaviour of the internals of component without making a change in those internals' code?

Comment: not behaviour, just hide certain elements, that's how you do authorization right?

Comment: Hiding an element is behaviour, is component logic. That's what I meant.

Comment: correct. I don't have to write my code into those components, the logic is done in one HOC.